# Unity Engine - Move the Object According to Image tracking

Tags: unity, vuforia

**Motive :** Want to develop Software which will track the Pad and move the four views of object accordingly.
**What I did/Current Knowledge :** I had placed the four camera around the object and change their viewport accordingly. Then, using Vuforia, tracked the pad(Image).
**Problem :** As I am beginner in Unity. I don't know how to move the object as the pad moves i.e. i don't want AR Projection on pad. but i want to use pad to move the object.
You can see my progress and work i done in these images. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRIkw.jpg
Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you duplicated this question to add pictures: [Unity : Move the Object According to Image tracking](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/121109/unity-move-the-object-according-to-image-tracking) - You know you can just edit your posts instead? Also, this is very similar to [a question by honey](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/121095/moving-the-rendered-object-the-projection-perspectives-based-on-an-ar-marker)...