# Moving the rendered object/the projection perspectives based on an AR marker

Tags: unity, augmented-reality, vuforia

I saw this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p57ZHnR0QlE) and now I am trying to making it.

I have used Vuforia AR Camera Pulgin, and so far tracked the image on a marker but the problem is getting the four projections of the 3D object on a screen. Here is an [example](http://kotaku.com/fan-creates-awesome-holographic-pokemon-projections-1760526138) of what it looks like.

I have used Viewport Rect method with four cameras but that does not seem to change the projections as I move the marker.

Comment: "problem is getting the four projections of the 3D object on a screen" Is it? You already have an accepted answer to this in [your previous question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/120036/how-to-render-multiple-projections-of-an-object), which you said in a comment that you were able to get working. If your problem is **moving the rendered object/the projection perspectives based on an AR marker**, then *that* should be your title and the focus of the question (ie. delete the line about RenderTextures as that has no bearing on this movement logic)